# T-SQL: Distributing spent money per quarter onto milestones

Tags: sql, t-sql

currently I'm thinking about solving the problem described below with a SQL Query. However I was not yet able to come up with a really satisfying solution.
I can always solve the problem in the program which queries the database, however a SQL server-side solution would be preferred (because it's a lot of data and the server is much faster than my computer).

The scenario (MS SQL Server 2008):
Two tables, one is called "budget", the other one "milestones". budget contains quarterly spent money, the milestones table contains ... surprise, milestones.

```
Relation of table budget: (year, quarter, spent_money)
year | quarter | spent_money
-----|---------|------------
2014 | 1       | 1000 $
2014 | 2       | 2000 $
2014 | 3       | 1500 $
2014 | 4       | 1000 $

Relation of table milestones (name, date)
name | date
-----|-----------
MS1  | 2014-01-31
MS2  | 2014-02-28
MS3  | 2014-08-31
```

Now I want to find out, how much money I spent for each milestone. I assume that the money for each quarter was spent equally over all days.
Example: Roughly one third of the money of quarter 1 would be spent for milestone1, another third for milestone2. The last third plus all quarter2 and some parts of quarter 3 belong to milestone3. Expected result:

```
Milestone | spent_money
----------|------------
MS1       | 30/90 * 1000 $
MS2       | 28/90 * 1000 $
MS3       | 31/90 * 1000 $ + 2000 $ + 31/92 * 1500
```

Dividing the number of days of the quarter belonging to one milestone by the total number of days of the quarter gives me a factor which can be multiplied by spent_money per quarter.

My idea so far:
Create a virtual table containing all days (and dates) of all relevant quarters and the factor 1/[number of days of quarter], then join the budget table and multiply the money with the factor. The last step would be joining the milestone table and using the `SUM()` function for grouping by milestones, which has a structural problem:

I would have to join the milestones table on something like `ON budget_per_day.day <= milestones.date AND budget_per_day.day >= milestones.[previous date]`. One solution could be adding a start date to the milestones relation or first joining milestones to itself with the date of the previous milestone as the start date for the next milestone.

The resulting query would look like:

```
SELECT milestones.name,SUM(alldays.factor*budget.spent_money) FROM
((SELECT 2014-01-01 AS day_date, 1 AS day_id, 1/90 AS factor
UNION SELECT 2014-01-02, 2, 1/90
...
UNION SELECT 2014-08-15, 2) AS alldays
LEFT JOIN budget ON alldays.date>budget.quarter_start_date AND alldays.date<=budget.quarter_end_date)
LEFT JOIN milestones ON alldays.date>milestones.start_date AND alldays.date<=date
GROUP BY milestones.name
```

Any idea for better performance is highly appreciated.

Sven

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would go a long way, descriptions of data/results take a lot more work to follow.  Also, code that you've tried so far and the issue with the results you're getting will make this a better question.

Comment: So a milestone is considered to go from the beginning of the year/quarter, or from the previous milestone?

Comment: yes, a milestone starts after the previous has ended. however some milestones have a duration 0 days, because they end on the same day as the previous.

Answer (score 0):

After some more hours of research, I came up with the following solution. Hopefully I didn't destroy anything while reducing the query to its important core. I'm pretty sure that there is a better solution out there, but for now it works for me (10 Mio results in 4 minutes). I did not include the SUM() for the actual_per_day column.

```
    WITH sample AS (
    SELECT CAST('2010-01-01' AS date) AS dt
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
    FROM sample s
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) <= CAST('2014-12-31' AS date)),

    /****************************************************/

    cte_gates AS (
    SELECT 
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY project,milestone),
    *
    FROM milestones
    )

    /****************************************************/

    SELECT dt,b.project,b.quarter_start,quarter_days,
    CAST((b.spent_money) AS money)/CAST((dates.quarter_days) AS money) AS [actual_per_day],
    gates.gate,gates.cur_gate_date,gates.gate_start_date
    FROM 
    ((SELECT dt,
    CAST(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, dt), 0) AS date) AS [quarter_start],      
    DATEDIFF(day,CAST(DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, dt), 0) AS date),DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, dt) + 1, 0)))+1 AS 'quarter_days'
    FROM sample 
    ) dates
    LEFT JOIN budget b ON dates.quarter_start=b.quarter_start)
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT cte1.project,cte1.milestone, cte1.date as cur_gate_date,
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY,1,cte2.date) AS date) AS gate_start_date
    FROM cte_gates cte1
    LEFT JOIN cte_gates cte2 ON cte1.rownum=cte2.rownum+1 AND cte1.project=cte2.project) gates ON gates.project=b.project AND dt<=gates.cur_gate_date AND dt>=gates.gate_start_date
    ORDER BY b.project,dates.dt ASC
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```